# android mk to bp file conversion

Tags: android

I am converting android.mk to android.bp using Androidmk tool, So to run the android.bp which is newly generated do i have to add any instructions or build system will take-care of it?

I would like to hear some answers

Comment: fyi [Soong Build System](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build)

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of Android application you are building? It looks like the build framework you converted to is really only meant for system applications compiled along with a full Android system.